# Common Lisp: Passing Symbol to Macro

Tags: macros, arguments, metaprogramming, common-lisp, symbols

The purpose of this macro is to create a macro that gives a name to accessing a certain key of  an associated list.

```
(defmacro generate-accessor (key-symbol prefix)
  (let ((mac-name 
          (intern (string-upcase (concatenate 'string
                                              prefix "-"
                                              (string key-symbol))))))
    `(defmacro ,mac-name (alis) `(assoc ,',key-symbol ,alis))))
```

So when I try it -

```
CL-USER> (generate-accessor 'a "alist")
; ERROR> 'A cannot be coerced to a string.
```

and yet...

```
CL-USER> (string 'a)
; RESULT> "A"
```

So I try again using SYMBOL-NAME to coerce the symbol into a string

```
(defmacro generate-accessor (key-symbol prefix)
  (let ((mac-name 
          (intern (string-upcase (concatenate 'string
                                              prefix "-"
                                              (symbol-name key-symbol))))))
    `(defmacro ,mac-name (alis) `(assoc ,',key-symbol ,alis))))
```

This time when I try it -

```
CL-USER> (generate-accessor 'a "alist")
; ERROR> The value 'A is not of type SYMBOL.
```

and yet...

```
CL-USER> (symbol-name 'a)
; RESULT>"A"
CL-USER> (symbolp 'a)
; RESULT>T
```

Whenever I use `'a` outside of my macro, it gets automatically interned as a symbol like I expect.  Yet somehow when I pass `'a` to my macro, it arrives as a quoted chunk.  I don't understand why it isn't being evaluated, especially at a point before the backquote begins.  I know I am not understanding something fundamental to Lisp but I don't know how to see it right now.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`'a` is shorthand for `(quote a)`, which is the *list* that you're passing to your macro.  Macro arguments are not evaluated, but passed as is.  When used as an argument to a function (i.e., not to a macro) `(quote a)` is *evaluated* first, and the result of *evaluating* `(quote a)` is the symbol `a`.  Consider, for instance, the difference between

```
(list 'a)           ===
(list (quote a)) 
; => (a)
```

and

```
'('a)               ===
'((quote a))        ===   
(quote ((quote a)))
; => ((quote a)) ;; which may also be printed ('a)
```

#### An example of using a symbol argument to a macro

Based on a request in the comments, here's a `defstruct`-like macro that creates some functions that incorporate the name of the structure.

```
(defmacro my-defstruct (name slot)
  "A very poor implementation of defstruct for structures
that have exactly one slot"
  (let ((struct-name (string name))
        (slot-name (string slot)))
    `(progn
       (defun ,(intern (concatenate 'string (string '#:make-) struct-name)) (value)
         (list value))
       (defun ,(intern (concatenate 'string (string struct-name) "-" slot-name)) (structure)
         (car structure)))))
```

Here's what, e.g., `(my-defstruct foo bar)` expands to:

```
CL-USER> (pprint (macroexpand '(my-defstruct foo bar)))

(PROGN
 (DEFUN MAKE-FOO (VALUE) (LIST VALUE))
 (DEFUN FOO-BAR (STRUCTURE) (CAR STRUCTURE)))
```

Examples of use:

```
CL-USER> (my-defstruct foo bar)
FOO-BAR
CL-USER> (make-foo 34)
(34)
CL-USER> (foo-bar (make-foo 34))
34
```

Comment: Alright, that's good to know.  Macros don't evaluate their arguments.  Do you see a way for me to achieve my aim of dynamically generating macro names the way that `DEFSTRUCT` does?

Comment: @SquareCrow I've updated the answer with an example.  Though it'd be easy enough to generate names for macros, I'll point out that `defstruct` is actually generating names for functions.

Comment: I see, perhaps I could generate functions instead.  After reading the answers given by yourself and Rainer, I arrived at a similar solution.  My original intent was to us my macro in `DOLIST` through a list of symbols, creating accessor names based on each.  I see that the symbol of the iteration variable, and not the variable contents, is passed to the macro.  I also see how `DEFSTRUCT`, which is passed symbols `A` and not quoted symbols `'A` (as in my first attempt) might construct function names from those symbols.  I am also doubting my quest for a flexible "alist struct".

Answer (score 8):

> Whenever I use 'a outside of my macro, it gets automatically interned as a symbol like I expect.

Why that. I expect that it is a quoted form and on evaluation I get the quoted object.

Remember: a macro transforms source code, not evaluated objects.

**Since your code does not evaluate it and you call `SYMBOL-NAME` on the quoted form, I expect that to be an error.**

You can debug the macro like other code. Print out what the macro gets as argument or just use the debugger to look at the backtrace and see the various variable values.

The macro `CHECK-TYPE` checks the type of some place.

```
CL-USER 15 > (defmacro generate-accessor (key-symbol prefix)
               (check-type key-symbol symbol)
               (check-type prefix string)
               (let ((mac-name 
                      (intern (string-upcase (concatenate 'string
                                                          prefix "-"
                                                          (string key-symbol))))))
                 `(defmacro ,mac-name (alis) `(assoc ,',key-symbol ,alis))))
GENERATE-ACCESSOR

CL-USER 16 > (generate-accessor 'a "alist")

Error: The value (QUOTE A) of KEY-SYMBOL is not of type SYMBOL.
  1 (continue) Supply a new value of KEY-SYMBOL.
  2 (abort) Return to level 0.
  3 Return to top loop level 0.
```

So the `CHECK-TYPE` complains that its not a symbol, but a list of two elements.
Which is expected, since the macro works on source code, not evaluated objects.

Btw., writing the accessor as a macro is already wrong. Common Lisp has functions - use them.

Comment: Can't say that I agree that it is wrong. My aim was to use `GENERATE-ACCESSOR` to obtain a result like the accessors created by `DEFSTRUCT` but for use with an associated list.  I may not have saved myself anything in the end, but I wanted to know why my experiment wasn't working.  Thank you for your answer and for demonstrating `CHECK-TYPE`.

Comment: @SquareCrow: DEFSTRUCT accessors are functions, not macros.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently you didn't notice that `'a` wasn't evaluated when your macro was called:

```
(defmacro generate-accessor (**key-symbol** prefix)
  (let ((mac-name 
          (intern (string-upcase (concatenate 'string
                                              prefix "-"
                                              (string **key-symbol**))))))
    `(defmacro ,mac-name (alis) `(assoc ,',key-symbol ,alis))))
```

**key-symbol** is just substituted rather than evaluated. For example, define a simpler macro as follows:

```
(defmacro foo (a b)                                                                                          
  (let ((x a) (y b) (z (concatenate 'string (string a) b)))                                                  
    `(print (list ,a ,b ,x ,y ,z))))
```

Pass in 'a and "b":

```
CL-USER> (foo 'a "b")                                                                                        
; Evaluation aborted on #<SIMPLE-TYPE-ERROR expected-type: SB-KERNEL:STRING-DESIGNATOR datum: 'A>.
```

After execute `(setq a 1)`, pass in a and "b":

```
CL-USER> (foo a "b")                                                               
(1 "b" 1 "b" "Ab")                                                                                           
(1 "b" 1 "b" "Ab")
```

You can figure out that **a** (without quotation mark) is just **literally substituted** into the `let` clause since there is no eval comma in it.

To fix that, you can pass in a symbol without quotation mark, or rewrite your macro into a function like this:

```
(defun generate-accessor (key-symbol prefix)
  (eval
    (let ((mac-name 
             (intern (string-upcase (concatenate 'string
                                                 prefix "-"
                                                 (string key-symbol))))))
      `(defmacro ,mac-name (alis) `(assoc ',key-symbol ,alis)))))
```

But this is not the final answer -- how would you evaluate `key-symbol` while keeping `alis` untouched? I think this is impossible.

Maybe you could change the inner `defmacro` into `defun` as well:

```
(defun generate-accessor (key-symbol prefix)
  (eval
    (let ((mac-name 
           (intern (string-upcase (concatenate 'string
                                               prefix "-"
                                               (string key-symbol))))))
      `(defun ,mac-name (alis) (assoc ',key-symbol alis)))))
```

It works!

```
CL-USER> (generate-accessor 'a "x")                                                              
X-A
```

Macro is powerful, but don't overuse!